# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named - when attempting to import files from another folder

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to run a code that imports .py files form another folder. The hierarchy is as follows:

[image]

Here's the section of the code on my AppiumTest file where I call the imports:

```
from appium import webdriver
import unittest
from test.pageObj.LoginPage import LoginActivity
from test.pageObj.HomePage import HomeActivity
```

When attempting to run I get this error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.pageObj'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the below code instead and see whether it works?

from pageObj.LoginPage import LoginActivity

from pageObj.HomePage import HomeActivity

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from pageObj.LoginPage import LoginActivity
from pageObj.HomePage import HomeActivity
```

Answer (score 1):

1. __ init __.py in pageObj

```
from .HomePage import HomeActivity
from .LoginPage import LoginActivity
```

2. AppiumTest.py

```
from test.pageObj import HomePage
from test.pageObj import LoginPage
```

3. package and __ init __

> Python defines two types of packages, regular packages and namespace packages. Regular packages are traditional packages as they existed in Python 3.2 and earlier. A regular package is typically implemented as a directory containing an **init**.py file. When a regular package is imported, this **init**.py file is implicitly executed, and the objects it defines are bound to names in the package’s namespace. The **init**.py file can contain the same Python code that any other module can contain, and Python will add some additional attributes to the module when it is imported.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to include the parent directory in the import statement. `from pageobj import LoginActivity` should work.